# Altering STATIC_URL depending on value of request.is_secure

Tags: python, django

Just for some context, I am testing running a Django (1.4) app behind nginx+gunicorn on webfaction in order to run the admin parts securely. This is working fine. The nginx proxy is redirecting requests from `http://domain.com/admin` to `https://domain.com/admin` and Django is serving everything up without issue. The greater issue is the static files. I have these being served up from a separate static directory that is accessed both via http and https. My problem is how to render the static urls in my app's templates as well as the admin interface templates in such a way that the appropriate prefix is applied (http or https) depending on whether the request is secured or not.

For my app's templates, I've used the `{{ STATIC_URL }}path/to/resource` convention, which allows me to easily adjust the STATIC_URL context variable in a template_context_processor function. But this doesn't have any effect on the administrative templates which use the `{% static path/to/resource %}` templatetag to render the url.

The best I have come up with is to make two url options in **settings.py**:

```
STATIC_URL = 'https://mydomain.com/static/'
NON_SECURED_STATIC_URL = 'http://mydomain.com/static/'
```

Then added the following function to **TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS**:

```
def set_static_url(request):
    if not request.is_secure():
        return { 'STATIC_URL': settings.NON_SECURED_STATIC_URL }
```

This is actually working, but it seems rather hackish. I'm also quite new to Django and I feel there must be a better or more appropriate way of doing this.

Comment: Not sure why you think that's hackish. That's a perfectly appropriate way of using a context processor.

Comment: In an ideal world, I would rather be using the `static` templatetag in all my templates, rather than using a different method of referencing the static url from what the admin templates do. From what I can gather looking at django's source, there isn't a place to intercept/manipulate setting values BEFORE tags get to them.